# I am trying to use htaccess to redirect subdomain to domain query

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect myname.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/search/?q=myname

I have tried:

```
ReWriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(.*)\.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/search/?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The redirect works but sends me to www.mydomain.com/search/?q= it does not include the search string (ie. subdomain)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `%1` instead since you are capturing group in `RewriteCond`:

```
ReWriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(.*)\.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/search/?q=%1 [QSA,L]
```